# Cannot get AutoAdminLogon key value. Visual Basic .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to check if a remote computer is autologin or not. I am using the bellow code but I am getting a default value as answer. It looks like it cannot get any value for autologin but that value actually exist. I would appreciate any help

```
Private Sub askComputer(ByVal computer, ByRef text)

    Dim environmentKey As RegistryKey

    environmentKey =   RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computer).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", False)

    text = environmentKey.GetValue("AutoAdminLogon", "?").ToString
    MsgBox(text)
    'For Each valueName As String In environmentKey.GetValueNames()

    'MsgBox(valueName)
    'MsgBox(environmentKey.GetValue(valueName).ToString())
    'Next

    ' Close the registry key.
    environmentKey.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: I have noted that I cannot get HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultUserName either. However I can get other keys like  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ReportBookOk

Answer (score 0):

This code will solve the problem. It can get the AutoAdminLogon key on any computer on the network

```
 Private Sub askComputer1(ByVal computer)

    MsgBox(computer)
    Dim environmentKey As RegistryKey
    Dim val1 As String, val2 As String
    environmentKey = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, computer, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon")

    val1 = environmentKey.GetValue("AutoAdminLogon").ToString()
    val2 = environmentKey.GetValue("DefaultUserName").ToString()
    MsgBox(val1 & "   " & val2)
    environmentKey.Close()

End Sub
```